# Setting a textfield in a class in but displaying a number?

Tags: class, textfield, actionscript-3

I'm learn as3, and building some exercises from the adobe online tutorials. I'm trying to do a very simple task and I think my code is exactly the same as the tutoriala nd it's not working! I just can't work it out...

I'm trying to change the textfield in a button from that buttons class.

The button is called GameButton, the textfield is called blabel and is classic text and dynamic text. Here is the code for the GameButton class. Instead of displaying "Click" as below it just changes the label to the number 1. The trace statement is working etc it is going there, but the text isn't passing through or something. Please help!!!

package  {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;


public class GameButton extends MovieClip {


    public function GameButton() {
        trace("Gamebutton has been created");
        this.blabel.text = "Click";
        stop();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Children instances placed on the Stage in Flash Professional cannot be accessed by code from within the constructor of a parent instance since they have not been created at that point in code execution. Before accessing the child, the parent must instead either create the child instance by code or delay access to a callback function that listens for the child to dispatch its Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE event.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html

Answer (score 0):

The long and short of it is you can create the button in code, or else you can try listening for added to stage events coming from the parent object you're adding the children to (maybe the stage, maybe another DisplayObjectContainer).  The problem with the listening method is I'm not sure how you would know which child just dispatched the event without making some messy code.  I think the first option is generally easier and makes more sense, the only caveat is that you have to place the instances using x/y coordinates or apply scaleX, scaleY to stretch or shrink objects instead of doing it using the authoring tool.  You can still use the drag and drop parts of flash to figure out coordinates and build individual movie clips etc.

Enough talk on to some code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;


    public class GameButton extends MovieClip {

        private var blabel:TextField; //This can be any display object class or a class that extends from a display object class (Sprite, MovieClip, MyCustomButton etc.)

        public function GameButton() {
            blabel = new TextField(); //The type after new, should be the same, or a sub-class (extension) of the type used in the variable declaration above
            addChild(blabel);

            //blabel.x=10; //optional over ten pixels from left
            //blabel.y=10; //optional down ten pixels from top
            //blabel.scaleX=.5; //optional half the width
            //blabel.scaleY=2; //optional 2 times taller

            trace("Gamebutton has been created");
            blabel.text = "Click";
            stop();

        }

    }
}
```